# Какой вариант верный?

Tags: пунктуация

"Пару раз мы столкнулись в непонимании и я плакала далеко не от счастья".
"Пару раз мы столкнулись в непонимании, и я плакала далеко не от счастья".

Answer (score 1):

Я бы запятую поставила. Во-первых, потому что, если два раза был конфликт, вовсе не значит, что плакала тоже  два раза. А может, и между конфликтами тоже. Во-вторых, сначала был конфликт, а потом плакала. Это дает мне право не считать "пару раз" общим членом.

Answer (score 1):

Так это и зависит от смысла. Если пару раз столкнулись и плакала - то и запятая не нужна.
А если пару раз столкнулись - а плакала вообще, то нужна. Вопросы - к автору.

Comment: Повторю: я считаю, что запятая нужна!. НЕт общего второстепенного члена. Два обоснования в моем ответе. Третье: на то, что здесь нет общего члена, указывает и разная видовая отнесенность глаголов.

Comment: Общий член - пару раз. В случае если "плакала" каждый раз после "столкнулась"

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, потому что есть общее обстоятельство, относящееся к обеим частям этого сложного предложения. Но смысл первой части не совсем понятен. Что значит "столкнулись в непонимании"? Может быть, лучше так: "Пару раз мы столкнулись из-за непонимании и я плакала далеко не от счастья"?

Comment: Думаю, "столкнулись в непонимании" - это окказиональное, авторское употребление словосочетания. Оно создает образ, хотя и не является формально правильным.

Comment: Формально-то оно как раз правильно. Столкнулись (находясь) в непонимании. Как в ярости, злобе или там гневе. А может и в любви.

Comment: Да, пожалуй. В общем, мне этот оборот нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, поскольку это сложносочиненное предложение без общего второстепенного члена.

Answer (score 0):

> Повторю: я считаю, что запятая нужна!. НЕт общего второстепенного члена. Два обоснования в моем ответе. Третье: на то, что здесь нет общего члена, указывает и разная видовая отнесенность глаголов.

А если  изменить так: *Пару раз мы **сталкивались** в непонимании и я плакала далеко не от счастья*. Здесь оба глагола несовершенного вида. А на смысл это как-то влияет?